# using inner join and left join for the same table separately

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

there are 3 tables: sale, salesman, commission

foreign key `sale_id` belongs to both sale and commission tables

foreign key `salesman_id` belongs to both salesman and commission tables

there are some salesman who are also customers. people with the same name and the job are the same people.

```
select salesman.salesman_name, salesman.job_title
from salesman
left join commission
using (salesman_id)
where commission.sale_id IS NULL
```

this is my mysql code to find the salesman who did not sell any items

now i'm asked to find the name of the salesman who sold an item to these people

```
select sale.customer_name, sale.customer_job, salesman.salesman_name, salesman.job_title
from salesman
inner join sale
on sale.customer_name=salesman.salesman_name
AND sale.customer_job=salesman.job_title
left join commission
using (salesman_id)
WHERE commission.sale_id IS NULL
```

this is how far i've got. the problem is now i have the customers and i have to use their `sale_id`s to go to the `commission` table, so, i can use `salesman_id`s now and go to the `salesman` table to find the salesman's name.

but how? i thought i should do this:

```
inner join commission
on sale.sale_id=commission.sale_id
```

but i've used left join commission already, how's that going to happen?

Comment: If commission.sale_id is the only column that shows whether or not a salesman has sold an item and you're looking for salesmen who sold something why are you still using IS NULL in your WHERE clause?  You basically include a join that does nothing but prevent you from seeing anything related to a sale.

Comment: i see your point but i still can't understand how to find the salesmen who has not sold an item **and** find the salesmen who sold an item to them

Comment: You don't have a column in `commission` where the customer id (=salesman.salesman_id) is stored? Mind you, with more roles like that, it's often wise to go for a polymorphism kind of thing: a `people` table with id & all fields all 'people' have, and a `salesman` & `customer` table using people.id, and possibly extra columns only related to their sales or customer role. That means _people_ always have _one_ id, which would make it easier than trying it on flaky things like name & job title.

Comment: yeah i agree with you and thanks for your comment, this is my homework though so i have to do it with the given tables only